# Mapping child classes with parent injected in the constructor using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, parent-child, automapper, constructor-injection

I have a following class structure:

```
class SrcChild
{
    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class SrcParent
{
    public IEnumerable<SrcChild> Children { get; set; }
}
```

so the SrcParent has a collection of SrcChild objects.

Now I want to map an instance of SrcParent to DstParent. Here are the destination classes:

```
class DstChild
{
    public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public DstChild(DstParent parent)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}

class DstParent
{
    public IEnumerable<DstChild> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The DstParent has a collection of DstChild objects, that use constructor injection to keep a reference to their parent.

Using AutoMapper, I tried the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* mapping configuration */
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcChild, DstChild>()
            .ConstructUsing(
                resolutionContext => new DstChild((DstParent)resolutionContext.Parent.DestinationValue));
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcParent, DstParent>();

        /* source parent object with two children */
        var srcParent = new SrcParent
        {
            Children = new[] { new SrcChild(), new SrcChild() }
        };

        /* throws an exception */
        var dstParent = Mapper.Map<DstParent>(srcParent);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The main part here is the AutoMapper configuration where I am trying to extract reference to the produced DstParent from mapping context. This doesn't work (the (DstParent)resolutionContext.Parent.DestinationValue is null), but maybe I'm completely missing a point here?

Another idea I had was to use a function to create the child values, something like this:

```
class Program
{
    /* Should produce value for DstParent.Children */
    private static IEnumerable<DstChild> MakeChildren(SrcParent src /*, DstParent dstParent */)
    {
        var result = new List<DstChild>();
        // result.Add(new DstChild(dstParent));
        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* mapping configuration */
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcChild, DstChild>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcParent, DstParent>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Children,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => MakeChildren(src /*, How to obtain a reference to the destination here? */)));

        /* source parent object with two children */
        var srcParent = new SrcParent
        {
            Children = new[] { new SrcChild(), new SrcChild() }
        };

        var dstParent = Mapper.Map<DstParent>(srcParent);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

but I don't know how (if even possible at all) to get reference to the DstParent object produced by the Mapper.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this or should I rather think of dropping this design altogether and get rid of the parent reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a solution that I found is not pretty, but it works:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<DstChild> MakeChildren(IEnumerable<SrcChild> srcChildren, DstParent dstParent)
    {
        var dstChildren = new List<DstChild>();
        foreach (SrcChild child in srcChildren)
        {
            var dstChild = new DstChild(dstParent);
            Mapper.Map(child, dstChild);
            dstChildren.Add(dstChild);
        }
        return dstChildren;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcChild, DstChild>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SrcParent, DstParent>()
            /* Ignore Children property when creating DstParent*/
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Children, opt => opt.Ignore())
            /* After mapping is complete, populate the Children property */
            .AfterMap((srcParent, dstParent) =>
            {
                dstParent.Children = MakeChildren(srcParent.Children, dstParent);
            });

        var source = new SrcParent
        {
            Children = new[]
            {
                new SrcChild() {SomeProperty = true},
                new SrcChild() {SomeProperty = false}
            }
        };

        var destination = Mapper.Map<DstParent>(source);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The destination has children initialized, with SomeProperty properly assigned by AutoMapper. Please let me know if you find a better looking solution.